# Full screen mode bug with dual monitor

Tags: vlc-media-player, xorg, kde-plasma-5

I have a bug in `vlc` when I enter in full screen mode, The video is in the middle of my screens as you can see here https://i.ibb.co/tbQN5Hr/ezgif-com-video-to-gif.gif.

It doesn't do it to me with another player like `mpv`, or when I enter in full screen with `youtube`, I don't have this bug,

My system:

```bash
➜  ~ neofetch
                   '                  
                  'o'                     ------------
                 'ooo'                    OS: Artix Linux x86_64
                'ooxoo'                   Host: Inspiron 15 5510
               'ooxxxoo'                  Kernel: 6.2.11-x64v1-xanmod1
              'oookkxxoo'                 Uptime: 27 mins
             'oiioxkkxxoo'                Packages: 1484 (pacman), 20 (flatpak)
            ':;:iiiioxxxoo'               Shell: zsh 5.9
               `'.;::ioxxoo'              Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080
          '-.      `':;jiooo'             DE: Plasma 5.27.4
         'oooio-..     `'i:io'            WM: KWin
        'ooooxxxxoio:,.   `'-;'           Theme: Artix-dark [Plasma], Artix-dark [GTK2/3]
       'ooooxxxxxkkxoooIi:-.  `'          Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3]
      'ooooxxxxxkkkkxoiiiiiji'            Terminal: alacritty
     'ooooxxxxxkxxoiiii:'`     .i'        CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-11320H (8) @ 4.500GHz
    'ooooxxxxxoi:::'`       .;ioxo'       GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
   'ooooxooi::'`         .:iiixkxxo'      Memory: 3224MiB / 7679MiB
  'ooooi:'`                `'';ioxxo'
 'i:'`                          '':io'
'`                                   `'
```

vainfo

```bash
Trying display: wayland
Trying display: x11
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.18 (libva 2.18.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 23.1.0 ()
```

```bash
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.96    59.93    48.00
 
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94

DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it, I edited the `kwinrc` file and set the `videowallEnabled` option to `false`.

Now I get normal behavior when I switch to full screen